# How to load a large animated gif for the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, animated-gif

My site will have a large animated gif (1900px wide). As you can expect, the initial load is very long and the animation is very choppy. Is there a better way to load the gif so it doesn't drag the site down (and make the scrolling choppy)?

Answer (score 2):

If you load the image at `1px` wide and `1px` tall, it won't affect your scrolling.  Here's a nice little CSS/HTML large image loading hack:

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" width="1" height="1" onload="this.style.height = 'auto'; this.style.width = 'auto';">
```

Load the image at 1px size, then when it's loaded, display it normally.

If you only want to load the image once the body has loaded, try this:

```js
function initBanner(){
  
  var bannerSrc = "http://placekitten.com/1000/1000";
  // contains the src of the image
  
  var banner = document.getElementById('banner1');
  // this is the emage object
  
  banner.src = bannerSrc;
  // add the src to the image
  
  }
```

```html
<body onload="initBanner()">
  <!-- when the body has finished loading, call function initBanner() -->

  <img id="banner1" src="" />

</body>
```

Comment: It's an animated gif so I have to load the full image. I wonder if I could lazy load. Basically, load the page then a load the gif without compromising the page itself. Make sense?

Comment: I would not have thought of that! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the image, then once it's loaded insert it somewhere in your page:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(image);
};
image.src = 'image.gif';
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da4k3b4k/)